# JSON.stringify: how to skip indentation for one (or more) objects

Tags: javascript, json, indentation

I want to indent all the object *except* for some specific sub-objects.

This is the closest I have gotten to solving the issue. In the example, I want to avoid indenting `color`:

```
let obj = {
    colorsPerValue: [
        { value: 0.0, color: { r: 240, g: 59, b: 32 } },
        { value: 0.5, color: { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 } },
        { value: 1.0, color: { r: 44, g: 162, b: 95 } }
    ]
};
let str = JSON.stringify(obj, replacer, 2);
console.log(str);

replacer(name, val) {
    if (name === 'color') {
        return JSON.stringify(val); // stringify with no indentation
    } else {
        return val; // return as is
    }
};
```

Desired result:

```
{
    colorsPerValue: [
        { 
            value: 0.0, 
            color: { r: 240, g: 59, b: 32 } 
        },
        { 
            value: 0.5, 
            color: { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 } 
        },
        { 
            value: 1.0, 
            color: { r: 44, g: 162, b: 95 } 
        }
    ]
}
```

Actual result (you guessed it, `return JSON.stringify(val);` returns a serialized `string` which is not what I wanted):

```
{
  "colorsPerValue": [
    {
      "value": 0,
      "color": "{\"r\":240,\"g\":59,\"b\":32}"
    },
    {
      "value": 0.5,
      "color": "{\"r\":255,\"g\":255,\"b\":255}"
    },
    {
      "value": 1,
      "color": "{\"r\":44,\"g\":162,\"b\":95}"
    }
  ]
}
```

```js
let obj = {
  colorsPerValue: [
    { value: 0.0, color: { r: 240, g: 59, b: 32   } },
    { value: 0.5, color: { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 } },
    { value: 1.0, color: { r: 44, g: 162, b: 95   } }
  ]
};
let str = JSON.stringify(obj, replacer, 2);
console.log(str);

function replacer(name, val) {
  if (name === 'color') {
    return JSON.stringify(val); // stringify with no indentation
  } else {
    return val; // return as is
  }
};
```

Comment: Do you want to "pretty print" your json, or what are you trying to do?

Comment: @MichaelHirschler Yes, that would be it. Some of the "lower objects" are "less interesting" for the reader and I need to let them un-indented, because otherwise they "obfuscate" the other interesting information around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could strip all whitespace in the curly brackets which starts with `"color":`.

```js
var obj = {
        colorsPerValue: [
            { value: 0.0, color: { r: 240, g: 59, b: 32 } },
            { value: 0.5, color: { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 } },
            { value: 1.0, color: { r: 44, g: 162, b: 95 } }
        ]
    },
    str = JSON
        .stringify(obj, null, 2)
        .replace(/("color": \{)([^}]+)/g, (_, a, b) => a + b.replace(/\s+/g, ' '));

console.log(str);
```